# Udev rules are not getting applied by ID_SERIAL

Tags: udev

I have a disk /dev/sdr. Below is the UDEV information for sdr using below  command:

```
sudo udevadm info -q all -n  /dev/sdr  

Result:
    E: ID_SCSI=1
    E: ID_SCSI_SERIAL=6000c292c50a3ebf1f64b0027ecd58b6
    E: ID_SERIAL=36000c292c50a3ebf1f64b0027ecd58b6
```

I have created a rule (20-clonedisks.rules)  as below

```
    ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="36000c292c50a3ebf1f64b0027ecd58b6", OWNER:="root", GROUP:="disk"        

    ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="36000c292c50a3ebf1f64b0027ecd58b6", OWNER:="root", GROUP:="disk"
```

And when i do below command

```
    sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

I expect for the above disk `/dev/sdr` I want to set user root and group as disk, but its not happening as expected

Comment: can someone point me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

These properties are generated/imported in `60-persistent-storage.rules`, and therefore are only available to rules that happen *after* that file. You should use something like `70-clonedisks.rules` or `80-clonedisks.rules` for correct ordering.

(Your custom rule is actually redundant because all SCSI devices are assigned the group "disk" in 50-udev-default.rules.)

Answer (score 1):

Ordering wise we can do if actual functionality works as expected lets say 90-clonedisk.rules

and lets take this is use-case where it cant be redundant
say we have a rule in 60-storage.rules /dev/sdr set to owner grid and groud asmlib

then I want 90-clonedisks.rules, which sets the user to owner and group to disk to set the /dev/sdr to root and disk instead of grid asmlib

Answer (score 0):

You can point it to a script file `RUN+="Enter File Path"`
You can script that using bash script like

```
#!/bin/bash
chown root sdr
chown disk sdr
```

Make sure you use `chmod +x script.sh` (replace script.sh with your script) and make sure #!/bin/bash is in your file or it won't work

Comment: this won't work, as udev can reload the rules and root will again change to grid